# How do I pick and record video using UIImagePickerController for iPhone?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, iphone-sdk-3.0, uiimagepickercontroller

I want to pick a video from iPhone for my application for uploading on the Web.
I am using the UIImagePickerController for it.

**For for opening picker**

```
UIImagePickerController *imagePicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
imagePicker.delegate = self;
imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;
imagePicker.mediaTypes = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:(NSString *)kUTTypeMovie, nil];
[self presentModalViewController:imagePicker animated:YES];
```

It opens the photo library and only shows the movie type content.
Now I have the following questions:

- How do I get the video when I select the video then it ready to play and then when I click on choose then its compression nothing happen .. even I am not able to cancel it.
- As we have separate folders in iphone then how do we open video folder?

If I am able to choose then how do I get video detail as delegate method is

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingImage:(UIImage *)img editingInfo:(NSDictionary *)editInfo {
```

and it has **(UIImage *)img** parameter. How do I get it as video?

Comment: any idea friends .. how we pick video

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2758466/select-videos-using-uiimagepickercontroller-in-2g-3g

Answer (score 2):

You're using the wrong delegate method. iOS 3.0 introduced `imagePickerController:didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:` to replace `imagePickerController:didFinishPickingImage:editingInfo:`. This new method receives an NSDictionary which contains a number of key-value pairs related to the chosen image/video; in your case, you'll want to check the value for `UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL`.

Comment: thanks Anomie.. I also mention issue in my post which should be solved first before use delegate that is `how we get the video when I select the video then it ready to play and then when I click on choose then its compression nothing happen .. even I am not able to cancel it.` and one more which is not so important now is `As we have seprate folder in iphone then how we open video folder`

Comment: any idea friends .. how we pick video

Comment: Hey Amit Batten ... diod u get the solution for it.. I also have the same problem