# Using UIImagePickerController to select video

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad, uiimagepickercontroller

I'm trying to design an app that can play videos/media off an IPad. I'm wondering if it's possible to use the UIImagePickerController to pick out video files that are stored on the IPad that aren't located in the Camera Roll.  When I use UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeSavedPhotosAlbum as the source I can get at photos/videos taken by the IPad but nothing else.  When I use UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary as the source my program crashes before the picker displays anything.  My photo library contains a number of files, some taken by the IPad itself and others I inserted through iTunes.  Any ideas?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5514235/how-i-pick-and-record-video-using-uiimagepickercontroller-iphone