# Display the Saved Video in iPad

Tags: ios, uiimageview, uiimagepickercontroller

I want to display the saved videos in Photo Library in popOver controller just like images.

**How can i show the videos in popOver controller?**

**My code for Images is as follow:**

```
if ([self.popoverController isPopoverVisible]) {
        [self.popoverController dismissPopoverAnimated:YES];
        [popoverController release];
    } else {
        if ([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:
             UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeSavedPhotosAlbum])
        {
            UIImagePickerController *imagePicker =
            [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
            imagePicker.delegate = self;
            imagePicker.sourceType =
            UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;
            imagePicker.mediaTypes = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                                      (NSString *) kUTTypeImage,
                                      nil];
            imagePicker.allowsEditing = NO;

            self.popoverController = [[UIPopoverController alloc]
                                      initWithContentViewController:imagePicker];

            popoverController.delegate = self;


            [self.popoverController presentPopoverFromRect:CGRectMake(100, 100, 150, 100) inView:self.view permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny animated:YES];

            [imagePicker release];
```

**Help me to solve this problem.**

**Thank you,**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to choose right mediaType:

```
UIImagePickerController *imagePicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeSavedPhotosAlbum;

//here
imagePicker.mediaTypes = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:(NSString *)kUTTypeMovie, nil];
imagePicker.delegate = self;
```

Comment: `Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'No available types for source 2'`

Comment: Do you test on old device?
I googled some answers:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9098918/uiimagepickercontroller-mediatype-kuttypemovie-runtime-exception
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2758466/select-videos-using-uiimagepickercontroller-in-2g-3g/3532404#3532404

Also try this:
`myImagePickerController.mediaTypes =
    [UIImagePickerController availableMediaTypesForSourceType:
        UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera];`

Comment: sorry but i can't able to find the solution.

Comment: What is your test device? People wrote that there are some problems with ipods for example.

Comment: My device is iPad3 with iOS 6.1.3